# How to use Multi-threading to simplify following python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have following python code which fetches live stock data from yahoo finance and update it into excel sheet...Does anyone simplify it by using Multi-threading to improve performance(So that it will update excel cell at the same time)...Here is the code

```
import bs4
import requests
import xlwings as xw
from multiprocessing import Process

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def bajparsePrice():
    baj_r=requests.get('https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/BAJFINANCE.NS/')
    baj_soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(baj_r.text,"lxml")
    baj_price=baj_soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'}) 
    [0].find('span').text
    return baj_price

def infyparsePrice():
    infy_r=requests.get('https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/INFY.NS/')
    soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(infy_r.text,"lxml")
    infy_price=soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'}) 
    [0].find('span').text
    return infy_price

def relparsePrice():
    rel_r=requests.get('https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/RELIANCE.NS/')
    rel_soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(rel_r.text,"lxml")
    rel_price=rel_soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'}) 
    [0].find('span').text
    return rel_price

def sbinparsePrice():
    sbin_r=requests.get('https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/SBIN.NS/')
    sbin_soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(sbin_r.text,"lxml")
    sbin_price=sbin_soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'}) 
    [0].find('span').text
    return sbin_price

def canbkparsePrice():
    canbk_r=requests.get('https://in.finance.yahoo.com/quote/CANBK.NS/')
    canbk_soup=bs4.BeautifulSoup(canbk_r.text,"lxml")
    canbk_price=canbk_soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'My(6px) Pos(r) smartphone_Mt(6px)'}) 
    [0].find('span').text
    return canbk_price

while True:

    wb = xw.Book('fetchlivedata.xlsx')
    sht1 = wb.sheets['Sheet1']
    sht1.range('B2').value = str(bajparsePrice())
    sht1.range('B3').value = str(infyparsePrice())
    sht1.range('B4').value = str(relparsePrice())
    sht1.range('B5').value = str(sbinparsePrice())
    sht1.range('B6').value = str(canbkparsePrice())
```

Comment: Probably you could spawn the functions using multiprocessing, and push the results to a queue which pop out to a single writer process.

Comment: You can have a look into this module ```gevent``` which provides ability to execute code concurrently.

Comment: An off-topic side note: you have a lot of boiler plate code. I would definitely refactor all parsing functions to one single function. They all do kind of the same. Have a look after the DRY principle.

Answer (score 0):

Joblib is a good one to know, really easy to use for parallel for loops.

Example (from their website):

```py
>>> from joblib import Parallel, delayed
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> Parallel(n_jobs=1)(delayed(sqrt)(i**2) for i in range(10))
[0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0]
```

Link:
https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/